# Does JSoup support getComputedStyle or the equivalent?

Tags: java, html, css, dom, jsoup

Does the document tree returned by JSoup when it parses an HTML document support  getComputedStyle on the individual document elements?

What I would like to do is inline the CSS in an HTML fragment so that I can insert the fragment into a larger HTML document, with all of its formatting preserved but without messing with any other formatting in the document.

The research I've done would seem to suggest that I can accomplish this by iterating through all of the elements in the document, calling getComputedStyle on each one, and assigning the result to be the style for the element.

Yes, I realize that this may very well bloat the resulting HTML by putting a bunch of redundant / unnecessary style information on the individual elements, but I'm willing to pay the price of larger HTML, and as far as I can tell, embedding the style inline like this is the only way to preserve the formatting exactly while also making the HTML fragments fully portable. (If you've got another suggestion for accomplishing that purpose, I'm all ears. :-)

Getting back on topic... If I can't use getComputedStyle (or the equivalent) with JSoup, is there another Java HTML+CSS parser that supports getComputedStyle or the equivalent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. Jsoup is just a HTML parser with CSS selector support, it is not a HTML renderer.

You may want to take a look at [Lobobrowser](http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp) which is a Java based HTML renderer supporting JavaScript and like. *I do not know nor guarantee that `getComputedStyle()` is supported by Lobo*.

No other tools comes to mind. [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) comes close as it can also access/invoke JavaScript, but [some Google results](http://google.com/search?q=htmlunit%20getcomputedstyle) suggests that `getComputedStyle()` doesn't work on HtmlUnit as well. It's after all actually also not a real HTML renderer as well.

Comment: Lobo hasn't had any new releases since 2009, so it appears to be abandoned. I don't think we want to solve this problem with 3rd-party code that no one is maintaining.

Comment: OK, so if there's no off-the-shelf tool for this, then I think what we would need to do to implement it ourselves is (pseudocode):

    find every embedded or linked style sheet in the HTML
    for each embedded or linked style sheet in reverse order
      parse the style sheet
      for each style specifier in it
        select all matching nodes in the HTML
        prepend the specified style to the beginning of the node's style

The ordering is important to ensure that later styles take precedence over earlier ones.

Does that sound right?

(Not sure why the code isn't showing as pre.)